# Dynamically extract a list of unique values from a column range in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I found this [example](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4032-excel-dynamic-list-of-unique-values.html) in an excel tutorial

The following image is my desired result. and the following formula is supposed to be able to extract the unique records dynamically. I know how to do this with VBA but i really want to make this a formula without using a macro.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $B$2:$B$9), 0)),"")`

I have tried the above formula as given in the example link above but it returns with error. I am assuming that this worked at some point in excel however it no longer works with Excel 2016. Can someone clarify why this formula no longer works? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question about 5 minutes later, so i read the patch nodes on the how match changed from excel 2008 to 2016. You need to use the index rather than the count.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9, MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$2:$B$9),0,0),0)),"0)),"")")`

Recommended edit to the formula to change the value returned on error to a blank:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9, MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$2:$B$9),0,0),0)),"")`